# What is the best way to handle enum prop in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components in combination with typescript

Let say I have a typescript enum

```
 enum MessageLevel {
   info,
   warning,
   danger
 }
```

And I have a styled text component, which should change text color `(green, yellow, red)` depending on prop passed to it.

According to styled-components documentation I could do something like this.

But this code looks quite cluttered.
May be there is another solution?

```
const Message = styled.div<{ level: MessageLevel }>`
  ${(props) =>
    props.level === MessageLevel.low &&
    css`color: green;`
  }
  ${(props) =>
    props.level === MessageLevel.warning &&
    css`color: yellow;`
  }
  ${(props) =>
    props.level === MessageLevel.danger &&
    css`color: yellow;`
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a map here, mapping the `MessageLevel` value to a color value, and skipping the conditionals. This is cleaner in my opinion:

```js
const mapMessageLevelToColor = {
  [MessageLevel.low]: "green",
  [MessageLevel.warning]: "yellow",
  [MessageLevel.danger]: "red",
}

const Message = styled.div<{ level: MessageLevel }>`
  color: ${(props) => mapMessageLevelToColor[props.level]}
`;
```

---

Alternatively, you could combine the `props.level` checks into one line, and use [ternary syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

This approach wants a default/fallback option. I used "gray" here:

```js
const Message = styled.div<{ level: MessageLevel }>`
  color: ${(props) =>
    props.level === MessageLevel.low
      ? "green"
      : props.level === MessageLevel.warning
      ? "yellow"
      : props.level === MessageLevel.danger
      ? "red"
      : "gray"}
`;
```